# Implementing SQLData interface for composite rows

Tags: jdbc, clojure, psql, pgjdbc-ng

I am following official psql user guide on composite types (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) and trying to implement SQLData for the `inventory_item` type https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/docs/current/user-guide/#_java_sql_sqldata.

As far as I understand the type mapping of the SQLData implementation should be attached to the active connection.
Which in my situation is not that easy (i am using clojure + clojure.java.jdbc + connection pooling). Also, it feels not right to add it to every connection.

Is there a way to set the mapping only once so every connection will use it?

The dummy implementation of the SQLData (readonly yet)

```
(deftype InventoryItem []
  java.sql.SQLData
  (getSQLTypeName [_]
    "inventory_item")
  (readSQL [_ stream _type]
    {:name        (.readString stream)
     :supplier-id (.readInt stream)
     :price       (.readBigDecimal stream)})
  (writeSQL [_ stream]))
```